# When is/isn't the monoidal unit compact projective?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, abelian-categories, projective-modules

I am interested in developing intuition for when the monoidal unit in a closed monoidal abelian category is or isn't compact projective.  As such, my question is not looking for a yes/no answer, but rather for classes of examples in which either a yes or no applies.  I will repeat my question with more detail and examples:

**Definitions and remarks**

Recall that in an [abelian category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_category) $\mathcal C$, an object $X$ is *compact* if $\hom(X,-) : \mathcal C \to \mathrm{AbGp}$ preserves filtered colimits.  It is *projective* if $\hom(X,-)$ is right exact.  Since all $\mathbb Z$-linear functors preserve finite direct sums and since (sm)all colimits are generated by finite direct sums, cokernels, and filtered colimits, $X$ is *compact projective* iff $\hom(X,-)$ is cocontinuous (=preserves all colimits).  In a monoidal category with monoidal unit $\mathbf 1$, the functor $\hom(\mathbf 1,-)$ is the functor of *global sections* or *global elements* or *invariants*.  Thus to say "$\mathbf 1$ is compact projective" is the same as to say "the functor of global sections is cocontinuous."

Recall that a monoidal structure on $\mathcal C$ is *closed* if $X\otimes : \mathcal C \to \mathcal C$ and $\otimes X : \mathcal C \to \mathcal C$ have left adjoints for all $X$; in particular, in a closed monoidal category, both $\otimes X$ and $X\otimes$ are cocontinuous.  It is not hard to prove from this that in a closed monoidal category, if $\mathbf 1$ is compact projective, then so are all dualizable objects.

**Main questions**

What is a class of closed monoidal abelian categories "that appear in nature" for which the monoidal unit definitely is compact projective?

What is a class of closed monoidal abelian categories "that appear in nature" for which the monoidal unit definitely is not compact projective?

**Examples**

In any semisimple category, all objects are projective.  In particular, let $G$ be a reductive algebraic group over a field of characteristic $0$.  Then the category of algebraic $G$-modules is semisimple.  This gives a class of examples where the answer to my question is "yes".  I know essentially nothing about algebraic groups in characteristic $p$.  I've been told that in general reductive groups in characteristic $p$ do not have semisimple representation theory.  Do they nevertheless have $\mathbf 1$ compact projective?  Under what conditions?

Consider the additive algebraic group $\mathbb G_a$, say over $\mathbb C$.  Its category of algebraic modules is the category of vector spaces equipped with a locally nilpotent endomorphism.  The only compact projective object is the $0$ object; in particular, the trivial module $\mathbf 1$ is not compact projective.

Let $R$ be a commutative algebra.  The category of $R$-modules is symmetric monoidal with monoidal structure $\otimes_R$.  The monoidal unit is $R$ acting on itself by multiplication.  It is compact projective, for somewhat stupid reasons.

Let $A$ be an associative algebra.  The category of $A$-$A$-bimodules is monoidal with monoidal unit $A$ acting on itself from both sides by multiplication.  This is always compact.  I believe, but could be mistaken, that it is projective iff $A$ is semisimple as an algebra.

For most schemes $X$, the functor of global sections $\mathrm{H}^0 : \operatorname{QuasiCoh}(X) \to \mathrm{AbGp}$ is not exact.  Said another way, the monoidal unit $\mathcal O_X$ is not projective.  But I don't have good intuition for naturally-appearing classes of schemes for which one can say definitively that $\mathcal O_X$ is/is not projective.

The finite-dimensional representation theory of a Drinfeld–Jimbo quantum group at generic $q$ is semisimple, so $\mathbf 1$ is compact projective.  At roots of unity there are different possible choices for which representation theory to take, and I don't know all the answers.

The Temperley–Lieb category is the monoidal $\mathbb Z[q,q^{-1}]$ category freely-generated by a self-dual object of dimension $-q^2 - q^{-2}$.  It is not abelian, but its abelian envelop is.  Said abelian envelop has the property that the monoidal unit is compact projective.  Deligne's category $\mathrm{GL}(t)$ is the abelian envelop of the free symmetric monoidal category generated by a dualizable object of dimension $t$.  It also enjoys the property that the monoidal unit is compact projective.  Indeed, this is a general property of categories presented by "string diagrams" with "skein relations".

There are many other categories that appear in nature.  What about your favorite class?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan In Temperley-Lieb? No. It's the free monoidal category on a self-dual object of that dimension. Given any monoidal category, you can ask how many braidings it admits. In the case of TL, there are precisely four (which are interchanged under $q \mapsto -q$ and $q\mapsto q^{-1}$).

Comment: Huh. Interesting. Ignore me, then.

Comment: Very minor point, for A-mod-A projectivity is separability of A which in enough generality is stronger than semisimplicity (though they agree for algebras over a perfect field).

Comment: @NoahSnyder Thanks!  And indeed I should have remembered that from your paper with Chris and Chris.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding schemes: on a scheme $X$, the functor of global sections is exact iff no quasicoherent sheaves have higher cohomology. By [Serre's criterion for affineness](http://amathew.wordpress.com/2012/08/01/serres-criterion-for-affineness-as-morita-theory/), for reasonable schemes this is equivalent to $X$ being affine, essentially because in this case global sections is a functor $\text{QCoh}(X) \to \Gamma(X, \mathcal{O}_X)\text{-Mod}$ and exactness is one of the only obstructions to it being an equivalence.

Comment: The unit is always dualizable, with (co)evaluation the identity map, but the duality only gives a description of internal Hom, not global Hom (which is needed to measure compactness/projectivity).

Comment: @David: ah, of course you're right. Silly me. And to pass from internal to global hom we of course need to apply global sections... so I guess I only have one comment then!

Answer (score 3):

I think Corollary 1.13.7 from Etingof's lectures (www.math.mit.edu/~etingof/tenscat.pdf) might be useful:

Given a multiring category (= locally finite $k$-linear abelian monoidal category with biexact tensor) with right duals, then the unit object is projective iff the category is semisimple. This is a continuation of what you said yourself in the beginning.

Also, $Rep(GL_t)$ is the Karoubian (not abelian) envelope of the free rigid symmetric monoidal category with one generator of dimension $t$. It is abelian when $t $ is not an integer, in which case it is also semisimple, so it's not very interesting in term of your question. When $t$ is an integer, the situation is more complicated - the category is not abelian.

An interesting example is the Deligne category $Rep(S_t)$. It is the Karoubian envelope of the free rigid symmetric monoidal category generated by a Frobenius-algebra-object of dimension $t$. This category is not abelian when $t$ is a non-negative integer, but it has an abelian envelope, which is a tensor category. It is not semisimple, and of course $1$ is not projective.